# Unable to access python file via python path

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pythonpath

I've got a project with the following architecture:

```
source/
├── data
│   ├── job.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── __pycache__ 
│       └── article_library.cpython-35.pyc 
├── graph
├── __init__.py
├── main.py
└── settings
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __pycache__
    │   ├── __init__.cpython-35.pyc 
    │   └── settings.cpython-35.pyc
    └── settings.py
```

And this is my python path:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/user/Documents/thesis/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

**source/settings/settings.py**

```
MY_TOKEN = "atokentodostuff"
```

**source/__init__.py**

```
from settings import settings
```

**source/main.py**

```
from settings import settings
print(settings.MY_TOKEN)
```

It output me that:

```
atokentodostuff
```

**source/data/job.py**

```
from ..settings import settings
print(settings.MY_TOKEN)
```

But when I interpret this code (whatever my position in the project) I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "job.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..settings import settings
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

How can I access the variable in my `settings.py` into the file `job.py`. And is there a way to make it launchable from everywhere?

Comment: Google "why do I have pycache?" for an explanation.

Comment: Now I know what is the purpose of __pycache__ but that doesn't help me resolve the path problem

Comment: Sorry, I only meant that as a side comment to help you understand. It wasn't supposed to answer the question.

Comment: I find this solution `python -m source.data.job` but I would like to be able to launch it like a normal script `python source/data/job.py` any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code snippet for source/data/job.py

```
from source.settings import settings
print(settings.MY_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Where should I launch my script?

Comment: you can launch script from any either source directory or any nested directory inside source directory, just make sure that you have set your PYTHONPATH upto to source directory.